# How terminate all defunct process after a main script recovery using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have an main script that create two children process using multiprocessing library. This two process can't stop if the main fail, it can't be like daemon. When the main fails and runs again, I can't create two new process childrens. How I can reruns the main and terminate the defunct process before create the new ones?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some specific code examples and errors that are being thrown.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't wrap your main loop in a `try`/`except` block, and kill the two processes in the `except` block before exiting the program?

Comment: I can't kill the process before exiting because I need keep it working until the main can get back. I don't have tried nothing yet. The main will fail some day and I need some error handling